# Is it possible to make ListView display a text obtained through its ListViewItem.Tag?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I'd like to fill a multi-column System.Windows.Forms.ListView with the items I've stored in a separate `System.Collections.Generics.List<CustomClass>`. I would like to avoid to store the data twice, once in the `List<CustomClass>` and once as a string in ListViewItem. Is there a way to make ListViewItem use some callback function to obtain the text to put in its columns from the Tag property, instead of using its Text property?

**Update**: I've tried [the OnDrawSubItem solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666093/is-it-possible-to-make-listview-display-a-text-obtained-through-its-listviewitem/2666125#2666125) and it worked, but I experienced strange window invalidation problems (the ListView was always redrawn correctly, but the other windows in the dialog weren't). However, I found what I was looking for: [ListView in "virtual mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx). It allows to fill the ListView with data from another source, which is automatically updated when the source is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what it is you mean, if your `List<>` is a of type `string` you can just add the strings to the list and they will display anyway.

If your list is a class then you could just override the `.ToString` method.

**Edit**

Based on your comment. You would need to do a custom draw on the cells. I think the [OnDrawSubItem](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=OnDrawSubItem&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=8ad4ec2e82acecdc) event is the one you want to handle. Then based on column id (which you will get from the `DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs` you can set the text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated by question, because I want to use a multi-column ListView.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no ListViewItem callback function like this. You can make CustomListView, and override OnDraw... methods.